# extracting numerical component from string

Tags: java

I am just wondering how am I suppose extract the numerical value for the string. I have a constructor that is :

```
public Calender(String month, String day, String year) {
}
```

I know I have to use the split() and Integer.parseInt(), but I am not sure how to use it.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Look in the Related section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to use it: look here

```
public Calender(String month, String day, String year) {

    int mon=Integer.parseInt(month);//converts month(String) to (mon)Integer 
     int dy=Integer.parseInt(day);//converts day(String) to (dy)Integer
     int yr=Integer.parseInt(year);//converts year(String) to (yr)Integer


}
```

Comment: You need to assign these values to fields, not to local variables.

Comment: As poster asked, so for his/her understanding i did it locally, the poster can declare variable to globally if he/she wants means. even poster didnt post more information at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Integer.parseInt(YOUR_STRING_HERE)`.